# How to run and break two python scripts simultaneously?

Tags: python, shell, sh

My issue is as title states. I have two python scripts, one of them is processing data, placing them in file and the other one forwards file's content via MQTT.

Currently I am running this shell script:

```
python3 detection/publisher.py &
python3 detection/demo.py &
```

However processes are given random PID's and to stop them I need to kill them.

Is there a way to run those two scripts simultaneously and stop them (with key interrupt for example) in efficient and/or elegant way?

Comment: This might be helpful - https://kuberneteslab.com/how-to-kill-multiple-processes-in-linux-with-grep/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html  - aka InterProcessCommiunications... if you want a quick and dirty solution your one script could write a "quit.txt" and your MQTT script could occasionally check for it and if, quit.

Comment: @FrancisWebb sounds nice, i could write sh script which would wait for my command and kill both of them

Comment: @PatrickArtner thank you for your reply, i really like it too :D Do i understand correctly that mqtt checks for exsitance of quit.txt and if it doesnt exist stops working, and informs via ipc the first script to stop working too? I have to ask, what is the "long and clean" way?

Comment: Are the two scripts running on the same machine, or possibly on different machines?

Comment: @Grismar it's the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems straightforward:

```
from time import sleep
from subprocess import Popen

p1 = Popen('python3 detection/publisher.py')
p2 = Popen('python3 detection/demo.py')

sleep(5)

p1.kill()
p2.kill()
```

Of course, instead of `sleep()` you could check for some condition, like a file appearing, or a keystroke. Or you could use something like a `Queue` to pass information between the processes.

Comment: I have decided to use script shell instead but i really like your comment as so i am accepting it :D